# gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Tags: linux, bash, gzip, tar

I have a Bash script that creates a *.tar.gz* file, encrypts, and then sends it to a drive. However, I cannot open the *.tar.gz* file afterwards. Here is my process...

Bash script that encrypts.

```
#!/bin/sh

# Tar the automysqlbackup directory
tar -zcf "red-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" /var/lib/automysqlbackup/

# Encrypt the tar file
openssl aes-256-cbc -a -salt -in "red-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz" -out "red-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz.enc" -pass 'pass:MySecretPWD'

# Remove the original tar file
rm -rf "red-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz"

# Upload to Google Drive
gdrive upload --file "red-backup-$(date '+%Y-%m-%d').tar.gz.enc" -p "jofhriout849uioejfoiu09"
```

Then I download the file and use

```
sudo openssl aes-256-cbc -e -in red-backup-2016-09-22.tar.gz.enc -out red-backup-2016-09-22.tar.gz
```

I then enter the passphrase for my file twice and I now get a file called

```
red-backup-2016-09-22.tar.gz
```

When I then try

```
sudo tar -zxvf red-backup-2016-09-22.tar.gz
```

I get

```
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

I have also tried renaming the file .tar and also tried

```
sudo tar xvf red-backup-2016-09-22.tar.gz
```

and

```
sudo tar xvf red-backup-2016-09-22.tar

tar: This does not look like a tar archive
tar: Skipping to next header
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Can you try unpacking a tar without the `z` ?

Comment: without the z flag I get the same error stdin: not in gzip format.  Without both z flag and filename .tar (no .gz) I get " tar: This does not look like a tar archive "

Comment: leave out the `-a` flag during encryption (or use it also during decryption if you need to base64 process the data) and use `-d` to decrypt, not `-e` (in the example above, the file was encrypted twice)

Comment: @ewcz With the -a flag removed and using -d as you said, the process worked flawlessly.  Thankyou very much for solving the problem.

Comment: Solved this issue by installing the binary version, refer [this](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/cassandra/getting_started/installing.html). Cassandra 4.0.0 isn't available, you can find 4.0.3 over [here](https://downloads.apache.org/cassandra/4.0.3/)

Answer (score -16, accepted):

This is probably because of your gzip version incompatibility.

Check these points first:

> which gzip

/usr/bin/gzip   or /bin/gzip

It should be either */bin/gzip* or */usr/bin/gzip*. If your gzip points to some other gzip application, please try by removing that path from your PATH environment variable.

Next is

> gzip -V

gzip 1.3.5
(2002-09-30)

Your problem can be resolved with these check points.

Comment: Mine points to **/bin/gzip**, and I'm still having this issue.

Comment: I have same /bin/gzip and gzip -V is gzip 1.5, facing same issue.

Comment: I have same /bin/gzip and gzip -V is gzip 1.6, facing same issue... any resolution?

Comment: I have same /bin/gzip and gzip -V is gzip 1.6, facing same issue

Comment: i have same gzip path and still the same issue

Comment: @Roopendra, can you document any situation where one released version of gzip will fail with a "not in gzip format" error for an archive another released version of gzip created? I can't think of a single situation where this answer could ever be correct.

Answer (score 98):

First check the type of compression using the `file` command:

```
file name_name.tgz
```

Output: If the output is " XZ compressed data", then use `tar xf <archive name>` to unzip the file, e.g.

- `tar xf archive.tar.xz`
- `tar xf archive.tar.gz`
- `tar xf archive.tar`
- `tar xf archive.tgz`

Comment: The same is applicable when `file <file_name>` returns `POSIX tar archive (GNU)`.

Comment: It worked for me even when I got the same output as @Hari from `file <filename>` command.

Comment: I had accidentally `wget`ed confusingly named html page as a tgz. This helped me realize it.

Answer (score 85):

This means the file isn't really a gzipped tar file -- or any kind of gzipped file -- in spite of being named like one.

When you download a file with `wget`, check for indications like `Length: unspecified [text/html]` which shows it is plain text (text) and that it is intended to be interpreted as html. Check the `wget` output below -

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz"

--2017-10-12 12:39:40--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... 23.72.136.27, 23.72.136.67
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|23.72.136.27|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Not Allowed
Location: http://XXXX/FAQs/URLFiltering/ProxyWarning.html [following]
--2017-10-12 12:39:40--  http://XXXX/FAQs/URLFiltering/ProxyWarning.html
Resolving XXXX (XXXXX)... XXX.XX.XX.XXX
Connecting to XXXX (XXXX)|XXX.XX.XX.XXX|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 17121 (17K) [text/html]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’

100%[=========================================================================================================================================================================>] 17,121      --.-K/s   in 0.05s

2017-10-12 12:39:40 (349 KB/s) - ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [17121/17121]
```

This sort of confirms that you haven't received a gzip file.

For a correct file, the `wget` output will show something like `Length: 185515842 (177M) [application/x-gzip]` as shown in the below output -

```
wget --no-cookies --no-check-certificate --header "Cookie: gpw_e24=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oracle.com%2F; oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" "http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz"

--2017-10-12 12:50:06--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)... XX.XXX.XX.XX, XX.XX.XXX.XX
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|XX.XX.XXX.XX|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz [following]
--2017-10-12 12:50:06--  https://edelivery.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
Resolving edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)... XXX.XX.XXX.XX, 2600:1404:16:188::2d3e, 2600:1404:16:180::2d3e
Connecting to edelivery.oracle.com (edelivery.oracle.com)|XXX.XX.XX.XXX|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Moved Temporarily
Location: http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1507827127_f44251ebbb44c6e61e7f202677f94afd [following]
--2017-10-12 12:50:07--  http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u144-b01/090f390dda5b47b9b721c7dfaa008135/jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz?AuthParam=1507827127_f44251ebbb44c6e61
Connecting to download.oracle.com (download.oracle.com)|XX.XX.XXX.XX|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 185515842 (177M) [application/x-gzip]
Saving to: ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’

100%[=========================================================================================================================================================================>] 185,515,842 6.60MB/s   in 28s

2017-10-12 12:50:34 (6.43 MB/s) - ‘jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz’ saved [185515842/185515842]
```

The above shows a correct `gzip` application file has been downloaded.

You can also `file`, `head`, `less`, `view` utilities to check the file. For example, an HTML file would give the below output -

```
head jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Output:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="/css/print.css" rel="stylesheet" media="print">
    <link href="/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <link href="/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The above shows it is indeed an HTML page which we are trying to unzip/untar - something that won't work. If it was indeed a correct zip file (binary in nature) the output of `head` would have produced garbage - something like below -

```
head jdk-8u144-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

Output:

```
x�rY�[ms�F������ڍtіl���DR���Ŋ��j
                                       $�$,`0�h�_����/��=�@Q�w+��ձ*�Hbfz�{�~�{�i�x��k����޾}����z���w����g�����{�޼�;{s����w���⹳�7�N����i�
�����}
�¿g��������ק���7��s�����폺î߹�����~i��j�/�����޿#���=��=>��߿{}��|�������������3���X���]9�ޠ����u�����%ğ�<^)�H�8�F�R�t�o�L�u��S%�ds5�2_EZn�t^��
                                                                                                                                                 �N3��(��<��|'�q���R�N�gq�Uv!�ۻ�p���rL��M��u��.�Q�5�T��BNw�!$��<>�7G'$�,Mt4WY�Gi"�=��p�)�VIN3����\ek��0��G
                                            �<L�c�ē�t-���2���G:Ϣia��I�<ʋg3���d�H����[2`�<I�A�6�W��<��C�������h��A0QL�2�4�-*
�x���Е�t%t1��f�>+A͂�,Lr�
                        �Fe:MBH��ɩ�
C�Q�r�S��<M�b�<,5���@���s��݉c��sp�f�=g��?��k���4�}��kh)�¹Z��#d�*{���-�.N�)�e��s:�H(VQ��3*�$2��rϨv�"o�_��!A�������B�l=A�|��@��0��1��5��4g�
�
���Se����H[2�����t��5�Df����$1���b$� h�Op����!Lvb!p��b�8^�Y���n�
                                                                          O��Ԫ߱��|��lW�lu��*�N�M���
�/�^0~�~�#��q��������K��;�d���aw4����ݎ'�~�7��ky�o���������t�'k��f����!vo���'o���     �.�Pn\�
               �+��K"FA{����n2����v��!/Ok��r4�c5�x$'�.�&w�!�%�ޠo������2���i
                                                                               �a0��Ag�d����GH)G7~�g���b��%�b��rt�m~�    �����t0��    <������������5�q�t��K(��+Z<��=���:1�\�x�p=t�`��G@F��    i�����p8�����H.���dMLE��e[�`�'n��*h[��;�0w'��6A�١M�x�fpeB>&���MO�������`�@á/�"�����(��^���n��=����5��@�Mx��d:\YAn���]|�w>��S��FA9�J�k!�@�
```

Try downloading from the official site and check if their download links have changed. Also check your proxy settings and make sure you have the right proxies enabled to download/`wget` it from the correct source.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for, I was trying to wget jdk but didn't noticed it required auth code for download, and was indeed downloading the html page.

Comment: One way of wget downloading jdk is to download it with chrome just like a normal file and then get the url link from the downloads. do a wget <URL> on the remote machine. You'll see a file something like jdk-9.0.4_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz?AuthParam=1520....  just untar it.

Comment: for me, I was downloading a html page by accident so the answer helped me confirm it. I cannot upvote it as it's at 69 votes though

Answer (score 29):

Just click first on that link and go to the HTML page where actual downloads or mirrors are.

It's really misleading to have a full link which ends in .tgz when it actually leads to an HTML page where the real download links are.

I had this problem downloading [Apache Spark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Spark) and [Wget](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wget)-ing it into [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_%28operating_system%29).

```
https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html
```

Comment: I faced the same issue when downloading the latest version of spark. Glad I came across this comment, helped me fix the issue.

Comment: Also after selecting download spark, it leads to this page.. https://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.lua/spark/spark-2.3.4/spark-2.3.4-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz and there you can find the mirror link for spark (don't always check the URL name)

Comment: elaborate please

Comment: @MohammadHeydari when you have link in your browser in address bar which ends with .../htmlpage.pdf for example, it doesn't necessary means that it's really pdf file behind it - it could be just another HTML page.

Answer (score 11):

Initially, check the type of compression with the below command:

```
`file <file_name>`
```

If the output is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) compressed file, use the below command to uncompress:

```
`tar xvf <file_name>`
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the `.gz` extension is wrongfully appended to the filename.

- Run `file foo.csv.gz` to know the actual file type.
- Rename the file to `foo.csv` or whatever the actual file type is.

Answer (score 0):

Add **"-O file.tgz"** or **"-O file.tar.gz"** at the end of the wget command and extract **"file.tgz"** or **"file.tar.gz"**.

Here is the sample code for Google [Colaboratory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Project_Jupyter#Industry_adoption):

```
!wget -q  --trust-server-names  https://downloads.apache.org/spark/spark-3.0.0/spark-3.0.0-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz  -O file.tgz
print("Download completed successfully !!!")
!tar zxvf  file.tgz
```

Note: Please ensure that the *http* path for tgz is valid and the file is not corrupted.

Answer (score -1):

[unxz](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unxz) worked for me:

```
sudo unxz fileName.xz
```

Answer (score -2):

```
cd /Whatever/Directory/Path/The/File/Is/In

chmod +x xampp-linux-x64-7.0.6-0-installer.run

sudo ./xampp-linux-x64-7.0.6-0-installer.run
```

It works.

For more information, refer to *[Installing XAMPP on Linux Mint](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?t=223639)*.

Comment: What does this have to do with a question about an archive created with tar and openssl? Your `.run` archive is created with a `shar`-style tool, which is completely different and not compatible with the tools this question is asked about.